# php regular expressions resources

Tags: php, regex

can somebody point me to a good regular expression resource (for php if it matters).
I am looking now for a book here [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=php+regular+expressions&x=0&y=0) but don't know which one is better. It would be great to find something simple to understand and a fast and interesting process of learning.

Comment: Thanks guys for responses and hope to see more here, i will check everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

The site also has a [list](http://www.regular-expressions.info/books.html) of regular expressions books.

PHP supports several regular expressions variants, but the most important is [PCRE](http://www.php.net/pcre) (perl-comptabible regular expressions).

The `mb_ereg` family, besides supporting several encodings, also supports several [variants](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-set-options.php):

```
j   Java (Sun java.util.regex)
u   GNU regex
g   grep
c   Emacs
r   Ruby
z   Perl
b   POSIX Basic regex
d   POSIX Extended regex
```

Comment: +1 but even though , I also asked maybe somebody know an interesting resource, I mean with some interesting examples, situation. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ seems a bit complicated for beginners, or maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Vad I think [the tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is pretty accessible for beginners.

Comment: Regular-expressions.info is designed _for_ beginners. You're not going to find any resource that breaks it down simpler than that. Just take the time to do their tutorial from start to finish, and you'll have a good grasp of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

[Mastering Regular Expressions by: Jeffrey E.F. Friedl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) is considered the bible of Regular Expressions books.

Also, as Artefacto mentioned: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a terrific resource with clear and simple explanations.

But the best way to learn is to play with them using a regex tool like [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/) (Mac tool)

Answer (score 1):

Along with http://www.regular-expressions.info, you might find it useful to get an interactive regex editor.

[The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) is a good, light-weight editor.

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is amazing, but costly.

[regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) a simple, online tester.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only place I've found an intro to regular expressions that's suitable for beginners. It's part of an online book called "Practical PHP".

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/8/0

Answer (score 1):

These are the only regex books you'll ever need:

[Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

[Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689)

Both are great tools for learning regexes in general, but they both have lots of information specific to PHP as well.